# output message overlapped during cmake concurrent build

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, googletest

I'm trying to make build-system runs unit-test automatically.
The problem is that test output was duplicated when i use -j option.
have possible solution...?

**Parallel build + consistent output**
similar to

```
   function()
        synchronized {
            add_custom_command("...run test...")
        }
    endfunction()
```

which is no cmake syntax

src - https://github.com/dearblanc/cmake_practice

< first build > 
[image]

< second build > - make failure by intention
[image]

< wow >

```
Running module_a_test
Running module_b_test
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set[-=u=p=.=
=[=-=-=-=-=-]- -R-u-n-n]i n1g  t2e stte sftrso mf rMoOmD U2L Et_eAs
t[  sRuUiNt e s . 
 [ -]- -M-O-D-U-L-E-_-A]. GGElTo
bCa:l\ Utseesrts \ednevairrbo\nvmsecnotd es_ewto-rukps.p
a[c-e-\-c-m-a-k-e-_-p-r]a c1t itcee\smto dfurloem_ aM\OsDrUcL\Em_oBd2u
l[e _RaU_Nt e s t . c c]: 7M:O DFUaLiEl_uBr2e.G
EETx
p[e c t e d   e qOuKa l]i tMyO DoUfL Et_hBe2s.eG EvTa l(u0e sm:s
)
 ["-A-A-"-
- - -a-.-g-e]t (1) 
t e s t  Wfhriocmh  MiOsD:U L"EA_"B
2 ([8   mFsA ItLoEtDal)

][ -M-O-D-U-L-E-_-A-.-G]E T1  (t4e5s tm sf)r
o[m- -M-O-D-U-L-E-_-B-1]
 [1  RtUeNs t   f r o m]  MMOODDUULLEE__AB 1(.1G0E1T
mCs: \tUostearls)\
d
e[a-r-b-\-v-s-c-o-d-e-_]w oGrlkosbpaalc et\ecsmta keen_vpirraocntmiecnet\ mtoedaurl-ed_obw\ns
r[c=\=m=o=d=u=l=e=_=b=1]_ t1e stte.sctc :f6r:o mF a1i ltuerset
 Esxupietcet erda ne.q u(a1l5i5t ym so ft otthaels)e
 [v a lPuAeSsS:E
D    "]B B01 "t
e s tbs1..
g[e t (F)A
I L E D  W h]i c1h  tiess:t ," Bl1"i
s[t e dF AbIeLlEoDw : 
][  M OFDAUILLEE_DB 1 .]G ETM O(D3U9L Em_sA).
[G-E-T-
-
- -1- -F-A-I]L E1D  tTeEsStT
from MODULE_B1 (96 ms total)
```

Comment: @Tsyvarev updated :)

Comment: i think the word "duplicate" made misunderstanding... I mean "overlap". coincidence of output from each module cause confusing builder..

Comment: While CMake *configures* the project, it is not CMake who *builds* the project, so CMake has no flags which prevents messages overlapping in concurrent build. Under MinGW *building* of the project is performed with `mingw32-make` utility (`cmake --build` is just a wrapper around this utility). This utility accepts `--output-sync` option for control level of messages "overlapping" from a concurrent build. See documentation for that option: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Output.html#Parallel-Output.

Comment: Note, that it is a **requirement** of Stack Overflow for **question post** to **include** the **code**. *Link* to the repo is insufficient for fulfill that requirement. See [ask].